# Pass string from view(Razor) to Editor Template using Grid column bound in kendo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to pass string from view (razor) to Editor Template using Kendo grid column bound. I am using Upload file (Editor Template). I tried passing string using "EditorViewdata()", but it is not working.

My editor template is:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("FileUrl")
    .Events(events =>
    {
        events.Select("onSelectFile");
        events.Success("onUploadSuccessFile");
    })
    .Messages(messages =>
    {
        messages.Select("Upload");
    })
    .Enable(true)
    .Async(async =>
    {
        async.Save("SaveFile", "Products");
        async.Remove("DeleteFile", "Products");
        async.AutoUpload(true);
    })
    .Multiple(false))
```

And my column bound is:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.FileUrl).EditorTemplateName("FileUrl").Title("File");
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `EditorViewData` is the easiest way. Make sure you are using it like this:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.FileUrl).EditorTemplateName("FileUrl")
                             .EditorViewData(new { stringName = stringValue })
                             .Title("File");
```

Then in your editor template you can get the value by calling `ViewData["stringName"]`.

Comment: i have one column as : columns.Bound(c => c.PartNo), now i want to send the value of "PartNo" to editor template using "EditorViewData". I used the below code to send it,but it is showing null always.   columns.Bound(e => e.FileUrl).EditorTemplateName("FileUrl").EditorViewData(new { stringName = "#=PartNo#" }).Title("File");

Comment: In your Controller, check your model and see if the value of `PartNo` is null. If it is then change its value to a blank string. Do this before passing your model to your view.

Comment: "PartNo" value doesn't have null value, it is always non-nullable.